# How to prevent font falling out of button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button for my page that I'm also styling it

```
<button id="logButton" >Iniciar sesión</button>
```

And then the css code

```
#logButton
{
    width:119px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left:35%;
    height: 25.5333px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle also](https://jsfiddle.net/xskr5q3o/).

If I add the bootstrap class btn it doesn't do that and neither the font size nor the width of the button changes, my question is **what does bootstrap do to keep text in place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a natural behavior of an element, with fixed height and width, content will always overflow,it's better to use `min-width` and `min-height`.

```css
#logButton
{
    min-width:119px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left:35%;
    min-height: 25.5333px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<button id="logButton" >Iniciar sesión Iniciar sesión</button>
```

and If you want to know about `bootstrap's` `.btn` here is css:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#logButton
{
    /* Removed height & width*/
    padding: 10px 20px; /* Added */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left:35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode a width. Using padding on the left and right sides. Here you go.

```
#logButton
{
    padding: 3px 15px 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left:35%;
    height: 25.5333px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide overflow of text then use {overflow:hidden} is css code.
if you want to keep text but not want to increase with then use {height:auto}